# Why can't I import java.util.Objects.equals

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Why can't I import `java.util.Objects.equals`? I would like to be able to use

```
equals(foo, bar)
```

Instead of

```
Objects.equals(foo, bar)
```

I can import other static methods in this way. Thanks!

Edit:
This question was poorly phrased. The real issue was that IntelliJ did not let me auto-import.

Comment: How did you try to import it and what error did you get?

Comment: You can. What's the benefit of this over `foo.equals(bar)`, which is more idiomatic Java? That's what `Objects.equals` does anyway.

Comment: I can able to import `import static java.util.Objects.equals;`
is there any error did you get?

Comment: @DaveNewton "What's the benefit" `Objects.equals` handles the case of `foo` being null.

Comment: `Objects.equals` will deal with the case where `foo` is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm able to import it, it's a static method so you need to use:

```
import static java.util.Objects.equals;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like this is currently broken in OpenJDK 11.0.6. After doing a static import of `java.util.Objects.equals` the compiler complains with

> method `equals` in class `java.lang.Object` cannot be applied to given types

Comment: Also not possible with IntelliJ.